# `exclude -namespace=Ext.ux.ajax` not working for sencha cmd 7.0

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I added code below to build.xml(root directory of sencha project), trying to exclude `Ext.ux.ajax.*` classes when build app.js

```
<target name="-before-init">
    <if>
        <equals arg1="${build.environment}" arg2="production"/>
        <then>
            <property name="build.operations">
                exclude
                    -namespace=Ext.ux.ajax
            </property>
        </then>
    </if>
</target>
```

But it seems not working, the output app.js still includes all `Ext.ux.ajax.*` classes.
I also tried `-after-init-defaults`, `exclude -file=xxx`, and it didn't make any difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Anybody? Sencha support?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
"output": {
    // ...
    "js": {
        "path": "app.js",
        "filter": "all" // because of this config
    }
},
```